# Why are 2D game tiles often lit from the top left?

Tags: 2d, lighting, tiles

I have been in to game programming for some time now, and recently ventured out in to trying to create my own pixel art. So I have learned the basics of lighting and shading etc. and noticed that several games will light their tiles from the top left. Such as Super Metroid and Axiom Verge highlighted in red here:

[image: Super Metroid Screenshot]

[image]

I assume because there is no distinct light source, one was chosen and consistently applied everywhere where possible?

Why does it tend to be the top left, is it to do with westerners reading left to right, top to bottom perhaps?

And bonus question, what is the reason behind the opposite side shading shown in the blue circle in Axiom Verge?

Comment: I think only the artists who made those specific tiles could tell you their actual decision-making process with any authority. For the rest of us, we'd be speculating.

Comment: Why not the top left?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because only the devs can answer this.

Comment: I'm not even sure that this consensus on lighting direction is as strong as the question may imply. As I search for other examples, I'm finding cases where even in a single game, different levels use a mix of top-left, top-center, or top-right lighting. Even if we assume artists choose between these three options by rolling a fair die, we'd expect some common patterns to arise just by chance. So I'm not sure the examples cited above are evidence of a shared underlying rationale the artists were following, or just coincidences (or in the case of Axiom Verge, homage to its inspiration)

Comment: As the answers and related comments already show, nobody knows for sure and all we will get here are opinion-based answers.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments and suggestions, I didn't think it would be so subjective when I asked the question. I didn't want to draw attention to the specific games in question and what the devs were thinking as they made it. I was more wondering if there was a general art or game design theory behind this lighting style? 

I guess by @DMGregory comment, so long as the lighting is somewhat consistently coming from above it makes sense to the eye and looks alright to a player.

Comment: Tangential: shaded relief maps [by the U.S. Park Service](http://www.shadedrelief.com/realism/) also use lighting from the upper left. They say using lighting from the lower right “is highly susceptible to relief inversion, an optical illusion in which mountains and valleys appear to be inverted”

Answer (score 1):

I've been thinking about this for some time too.

It's a pure speculation, but I think it's because the same lighting is normally used for the real-life writing desks (and drawing desks). You don't want the shadow from your hand to obstruct the paper, so if you're right-handed, you want light to come from the top-left.

So, someone who writes or draws on paper a lot might subconsciously consider this to be the default lighting.

Comment: While psychology is a soft-science, all action is derived from the chain of cause and effect happening in your brain. I like this speculation. I'll go ask some game developers and see what they think.